# How to declare and join list of completable future responses in java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8, concurrency

The flow goes controller layer -> Service layer

Here I'm calling processLOBTransactions (Async method) method from the controller layer

How can I **join** all CompletableFuture responses in the controller layer?  my requirement is  after the execution of the **processLOBTransactions** for each list element  from the controller, in the controller layer I wanna write logs kind of thing

Could anyone please give any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
**Controller Layer:**

  class ControllerLayer{
                pktransaction.getLineOfBusinessTransaction().stream().forEach((lob) -> {
                    CompletableFuture<Boolean> futureResponse = flPbtService.processLOBTransactions(lob);
                });

                  ***//HERE How can i join all CompletableFuture Responses,and i wanna print logs like all thread completed*** 

        }

**Service layer:**
class ServiceLayer{
    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<Boolean> processLOBTransactions(LineOfBusinessTransaction lobObj) {

             // Doing some business logic and returning the CompletableFuture as Response

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Boolean(true));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All the `CompletableFuture<Boolean> futureResponse` objects inside the forEach has to be stored in the Collection.
2. Assuming `parallelStream()` will not be used, ArrayList can be used to gather these references
3. Outside the loop, these references can be iterated and `get()` obtain the result of exception
4. `get()` might wait until the actual task completes, so it may be better to use get(timeout, Unit)` to have a deterministic SLA contracts
5. `get` can throw exception and be sure handle appropriate actions by catching the exception
6. if the `get` with timeout, could not complete within timeout, then you can request `cancel` if its not a high priority operation assuming the underlying task does not consume the interruption. (it a business logic)

```java
                ArrayList<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
                IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach((lob) -> {
                    CompletableFuture<Boolean> futureResponse = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Boolean(true));
                    futures.add(futureResponse);
                });

                for (CompletableFuture<Boolean> future : futures) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(future.get());
                        // or future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        //future.cancel(true); // if need to cancel the underlying task, assuming the task listens
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Option to skip foreach loop by doing `futureResponse.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(toList())`

Comment: @Akki, Thank you for sharing the shorter version. Unfortunately, the elegance of stream will lead to runtime errors. Future.get() throws checked exception. but join abstracts and throws exception at runtime.(we can explicitly catch exception in map and do the necessary operation to fix it). Replacing `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Boolean(true));` to `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {throw new RuntimeException();});` will cause the program to fail the complete collection process.

Comment: Yes, true for method that can throw exceptions foreach loop works best.

Comment: @Horse  thanks for the reply  Inside forEach method I'm calling a method with Async, so each method taking one thread, and meanwhile below future for each method executing with the main thread, could you please give a suggestion on how can i get all futures completed  status?

Comment: @Horse  --- ArrayList<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();


pktransaction.getLineOfBusinessTransaction().stream().forEach((lob) -> {
          flPbtService.processLOBTransactions(lob, headers,lobTransactionStatus,futures);
}); for (CompletableFuture<Boolean> future : futures) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(future.get());
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

Comment: @Horse ---thanks for reply-- the same thing i got with complete example https://nickolasfisher.com/blog/How-to-Make-Concurrent-Service-API-Calls-in-Java-Using-Spring-Boot

Comment: @SrikanthJanapati Glad you found working solution. Have a good day